# Ensuring Only Distinct Product Id's are shown

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014-express

Consider the following partial result set which was produced from this query (derived from creating a view in ssms).

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    dbo.LandingHeaders.VesselId, dbo.LandingDetails.ProductId, 
    SUM(dbo.LandingDetails.Quantity) AS Quantity, 
    dbo.LandingDetails.UnitPrice
FROM
    dbo.LandingDetails 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.LandingHeaders ON dbo.LandingDetails.LandingId = dbo.LandingHeaders.LandingId 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Vessels ON dbo.LandingHeaders.VesselId = dbo.Vessels.VesselId
GROUP BY 
    dbo.LandingHeaders.VesselId, dbo.LandingDetails.UnitPrice, 
    dbo.LandingDetails.ProductId, dbo.LandingHeaders.LandingDate1
HAVING        
   (dbo.LandingHeaders.LandingDate1 BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-01-06 00:00:00', 102) 
                                    AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-01-13 00:00:00', 102))
ORDER BY 
    dbo.LandingHeaders.VesselId, dbo.LandingDetails.ProductId
```

[image]

I want to get this to return only distinct ProductId's and the sum of their relevant quantities.

**EDIT**

For example in those entries where the vessel Id is 4 there are three lines where the ProductId is 22.  Ideally I would like it to return the following single line,

```
4    22    19.1   0.4
```

Thus far the closest I have got is as follows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ld.ProductId, 
    ROUND(SUM(ld.Quantity), 2) AS Quantity,
    ld.UnitPrice, lh.VesselId 
FROM 
    LandingDetails ld 
JOIN 
    LandingHeaders lh ON ld.LandingId = lh.LandingId
GROUP BY 
    ld.ProductId, ld.UnitPrice, lh.VesselId
WHERE 
    lh.LandingDate1 BETWEEN '20160106' AND '20160113'
```

which obviously isn't quite close enough. I'd welcome suggestions.

Comment: Can you include your sample data and desire output?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  see the edit I have added to the question.  It's a bit difficult to post actual data.

Comment: What are you getting back from the query that you've tried? What is wrong about the results that you're getting?

Comment: @TomH  Currently nothing, I'm being told that there is incorrect syntax near the Keyword WHERE.

Comment: Well `WHERE` should go first than `GROUP BY`, `HAVING` go after group by if you need aditional filter after the aggregated function

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  Spot on thank you!!

Comment: Next time include the error details on the question. That totally change the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need `DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY` should do that work for you.

And `WHERE` go before `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ld.ProductId, 
        ROUND(SUM(ld.Quantity),2) AS Quantity,
        ld.UnitPrice, 
        lh.VesselId 
FROM LandingDetails ld 
JOIN LandingHeaders lh 
  ON ld.LandingId = lh.LandingId
WHERE lh.LandingDate1 BETWEEN '20160106' AND '20160113'
GROUP BY ld.ProductId, ld.UnitPrice, lh.VesselId
```